# How can I convert django forms.py select items to a list in html?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, forms

I have a form with which I intend to capture student marks. I have an issue like I don't know the best way to put it so that I have ***student name and markfield beside it for all the students***. calling `{{ form }}` brings the form with select dropdown items(not what I want). Specifying form fields do not populate anything.i.e

```
{% for field in form %}
{{ field.student }}
{{ field.marks }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is the form

```
class AddMarksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, school,klass,term,stream,year, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddMarksForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['student'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Students.objects.filter(school=school,klass__name__in=klass,stream__name=stream[0]))
    class Meta:
        model = Marks
        fields = ('student','marks')
```

This is how I tried the html rendering

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'add_marks' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form %}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Student</td>
        <td>Marks</td>
      </tr>
      {% for field in form %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ field.student }}</td>
        <td>{{ field.marks }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  {% endfor %}
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
```

My models.

```
class Year(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(2018), MaxValueValidator(4000),])
    year_term = models.ForeignKey('exams.Term',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='year_term', null=True,blank=True)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(TeacherData,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Students)


class Term(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    exam_term = models.ForeignKey('exams.Exam',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True,related_name='exam_term')
    
class Exam(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    klass = models.ManyToManyField("students.Klass", related_name='klass',null=True,blank=True)
    

class Marks(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    marks = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100),] ,null=True,blank=True)
```

More models

```
class Klass(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(4),], help_text='E.g 1,2,3, 4')
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam = models.ForeignKey("exams.Exam",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='exam',null=True,blank=True)
class Stream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text='Name of the stream')
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass,on_delete=models.CASCADE,help_text='Choose a class the stream belongs to')
class Students(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #student_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE,help_text='A school must have a name')
    adm = models.IntegerField(unique=True,validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000000),],help_text="Student's admission number" )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,help_text="Student's name")
    kcpe = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(100), MaxValueValidator(500),], help_text='What the student scored in primary')
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,help_text="Student's Class/Form")
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,help_text="Student's Stream")
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,help_text="Student's Gender")
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True,help_text='Anything to say about the student. Can always be edited later')
```

Comment: hello, could you please add the `Marks` model?

Comment: I have added the mode;

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you basically want a table, where in the left column you just have a name (that can't be changed) and then in the right one a number field for the marks?

Comment: You are very right, that's all I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion based on the discussion in question comments.

```py
# models.py
class User(models.Model):
    is_teacher = models.BoolField(default=False)
    is_student = models.BoolField(default=False)


class Subject(models.Model):
    taught_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, limit_choices_to={"is_teacher": True})
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, limit_choices_to={"is_student": True})


class Exam(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Marks(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={"is_student": True})
    marks = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100),], null=True, blank=True)
    # no need for a subject field here, that is linked through the Exam object
    class Meta:
        unique_togetger = [('exam', 'student'),]
```

I have only written the important fields, you can add more fields that you need.

```py
# views.py

class AddMarks(views.View):
    def get(self, request, exam_id):
        try:
            exam = Exam.objects.get(id=exam_id)
        except Exam.DoesNotExist:
            # some kind of handler that returns (important!)
        context = {
            "students": exam.subject.students.all()
            "current_marks": Marks.objects.filter(exam=exam)
        }
        return render("add_marks.html", context=context)
    def post(self, request, exam_id):
        try:
            exam = Exam.objects.get(id=exam_id)
        except Exam.DoesNotExist:
            # some kind of handler that returns (important!)
        for student in exam.subject.students.all():
            marks = int(request.POST.get(f"marks_{student.username}", None))
            if marks:
                # if that particular marks field exists in POST and is filled, let's update (if it exists) or create a new marks object
                marks_object = Marks.objects.filter(exam=exam, student=student).first() or Marks(exam=exam, student=student)
                marks_object.marks = marks
                marks_object.save()
        return self.get(request, exam_id)
```

```html
<!--add_marks.html-->

<form method="POST">
    <table>
        {% for student in students %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ student.get_full_name }}</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="marks_{{ student.username }}" /></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if students %}
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save marks" /></td></tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr><td colspan="2">No student is taking this class</td></tr>
        {% endif %}
    </table>
</form>

{% if current_marks %}
    <h3>Currently saved marks</h3>
    <table>
        {% for marks in current_marks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ marks.student.get_full_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ marks.marks }}</td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

I did make a couple of changes. Most noticeable is the `Student` model, or rather the lack thereof. I have made the `User` flaggable as either student or teacher, allowing your students to log in and see their grades or perhaps sign up for classes.

Second, as mentioned in the code, there is no need for a `subject` field in the `Marks` model, as that data can be pulled from the `Exam` itself.

Lastly about what this does. It will create a form with a table in it, where each row will contain a field named `marks_<username>`. The field can then be retrieved in the `post` method handler. If the field is there and has a value, the view will either update existing, or create a new `Marks` model. If there are already any marks saved, they will be showed below in a separate table.

I have removed the form entirely as that is redundant in this case. If you really wanted to, somewhere else perhaps, this multiple-forms-on-one-page thing can be achieved by using Django's FormSet API. The documentation about that is [here][1]. That allows you to stack many forms of the same kind one after another, for editing many rows at once. But since we only really have one field, I find it easier to just handle that one field myself.

One last thing, I did not write any error checking and handling. That I will leave to you. Potential places that need treatment are the two except blocks, that need to return from the method so that the code below isn't executed. Some nice 404 page should suffice. Another place is the `int()` call around getting the `POST` contents. That might throw an exception if something non-integer is sent in. You should be able to handle that with a simple `try-except` block.

Comment: Hey mate, I have really thought this through. Friendly advice, you better like this! 

Comment: It looks like you have developed something in line with this sometimes??

Comment: No, just a lot of Django under my belt. Recreational programming, mostly. And today I felt like spending the evening writing too long answers on StackOverflow. My life in a nutshell.

Comment: What does this line mean?marks_object = Marks.objects.filter(exam=exam, student=student).first() or Marks(exam=exam, student=student)

Comment: `marks_object = Marks.objects.filter(exam=current_exam, student=current_student).first()` means “Find me all Marks objects in the database, where the `exam` field equals `current_exam` and the `student` field equals `current_student` (I have replaced the value names for clarity), and from those, get me the first one as returned by the database” (there should really only ever be one or zero). The second line you mention creates a new `Marks` object with the specified fields set. Keep in mind this is only created in memory. It is then saved to DB via a `save()` call.

Comment: I tried to substitute the view items into my project but didn't go through. Let me make add my models so you can se how to best help...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231587/discussion-between-michal-krejci-and-fakemake).